# python 3.2.3 ignore escape sequence in string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, formatting, escaping

I'm new to Python and I'm using one of the examples I found here to read lines from a file and print them. What I don't understand is why the interpreter ignores `\n` escape sequence:

#### Text file:

> Which of the following are components you might find inside a PC? (Select all correct answers.)
>
> A. CPU
>
> B. Motherboard
>
> C. Keyboard
>
> Answers: A, B, and E. **\n**Common components inside a PC include **\n**the CPU,motherboard, and **\n**RAM

#### Python code:

```
questions_fname="Test.txt"

with open(questions_fname, 'r') as f:
    questions = [line.strip() for line in f]

for line in questions:
    print (line)


f.close()
```

The result I get is strings like:

```
Answers: A, B, and E. \nCommon components inside a PC include \nthe CPU,motherboard, and \nRAM
```

I was just looking for a simple way of formatting long lines to fit the screen.

Comment: Python automatically interprets a newline to be a `'\n'` character, you don't need to manually add them.

Comment: The escape sequences are interpreted only inside strings in the source file, not when reading data from a (text) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code to get the wanted behaviour...

```
questions_fname = "Test.txt"

with open(questions_fname) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip().replace('\\n', '\n')
        print(line)
```

The `.rstrip()` removes the trailing whitespaces, including the binary form of `\n`. The `.replace()` causes explicit, user defined interpretation of your `\n` sequences in the file content -- captured as the printable character `\` followed by the `n`.

When using the `with` construct, the `f.close()` is done automatically.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have `"\n"` in the string, you have `"\\n"` since you're reading it from a file. If you want to have `"\n"` then you need to decode the string. Note that 3.x doesn't have `str.decode()`, so you can't use that mechanism from 2.x.

```
3>> codecs.getdecoder('unicode-escape')('foo\\nbar')[0]
'foo\nbar'
```

Comment: +1 - completely forgot it was 3.x (was just looking at tags while typing!)

Comment: +1 -- there is nothing like automatically interpreted escape sequences in text files. The working newlines in the text file have always a binary form. You can `.replace(r'\n', '\n')` to get the wanted behaviour.

Comment: Note that if you're reading from a url in python 3 with `urllib`, then `read()` etc. return byte arrays, not strings. Conversion to strings with `str()` will result in '\\n in the string, but byte arrays *do* have a `.decode()` method, and using it will result in strings that are correctly formatted (i.e. that print new lines when passed to the `print()` function).

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character only in Python script, not in text files. When reading text files, Python converts all backslashes to `\\`, so when reading the file, `\n` becomes `\\n` which is not a newline character

Answer (score -1):

**Sorry - this isn't valid for Python 3.x (I was looking at the tags), but I'll leave here as reference - please see @Ignacio's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14193673/1252759**

If you've effectively got a `raw string` that contains the literal characters `'\n'`, then you can re-interpret the string to make it an escape sequence again:

```
>>> a = r"Answers: A, B, and E. \nCommon components inside a PC include \nthe CPU,motherboard, and \nRAM"
>>> print a
Answers: A, B, and E. \nCommon components inside a PC include \nthe CPU,motherboard, and \nRAM
>>> print a.decode('string_escape')
Answers: A, B, and E. 
Common components inside a PC include 
the CPU,motherboard, and 
RAM
```

You may also want to look at the `textwrap` module if you want to wrap lines to a certain width for certain displays...